# Rewrite Rule is not working Properly

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-shortener

I have a custom page (test.aleemakhter.com/wp-content/plugins/camophoto/template/login.php). I want to change its URL like this (test.aleemakhter.com/login)

I have done it successfully by this code:

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ wp-content/plugins/camophoto/template/login.php [L]
```

But when i am opening (test.aleemakhter.com/wp-content/plugins/camophoto/template/login.php) URL its not changing into (test.aleemakhter.com/login). Its working fine in one way but not in other way. I think you got my problem.

I have tried this code but its confusing the browser

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/plugins/camophoto/template/login.php(.*)$     
http://test.aleemakhter.com/login/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^login/?$ wp-content/plugins/camophoto/template/login.php [L]
```

Plzz help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this plugin after you reset your .htaccess file.

1. Rename wp-login.php: http://wordpress.org/plugins/rename-wp-login/
2. HC Custom WP-Admin URL: http://wordpress.org/plugins/hc-custom-wp-admin-url/